# If-statement returning wrong answer

Tags: javascript, if-statement

I'm trying to get my function `printResult(total3,total4);` to show the text 'Safe' or 'Busted' to my parameters 'Player' and 'Dealer' depending on the total value of the variables; `total3` and `total4`.

When I'm trying to preview ANSWER in the console.log(ANSWER) I'm getting:
`Player: busted, Dealer: safe`
Im trying to get a solution for my ANSWER to show:
`Player: safe, Dealer: safe`

Is using two if-statement like I do in my code below the correct way of trying to get the total values of the var total3 and total4?

```
var c4 =5;
var c5 =1;
var c6 =4;
var d4 =1;
var d5 =11;
var d6 =1;

var total3 = c4+c5+c6;
var total4 = d4+d5+d6;

var printResult = function(player,dealer){
    var game1 = "Player: "+total3 +", Dealer: "+total4;
    return game1;
}
if (total3 > total4){
    total3 = 'safe';
    total4 = 'busted';
}
if (total4 > total3) {
    total4 = 'safe';
    total3 = 'busted';
}


ANSWER = printResult(total3,total4);
```

Comment: What do you see when you walk through the code as it's running using the debugger built into your browser?

Comment: *Really* read through what your statements do. You **cannot** get a result where both are "safe".

Comment: Why do people still think we're here to debug their code?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your syntax doesn't allow for that result.

If the first if loop evaluates to true, then the second must be false, and vice-versa.

And since the code within the if loops sets one value to safe and the other to busted, this will always be the case.

I assume that it's a blackjack style game and would suggest that you evaluate the variables separately, then check to see who the winner is after that.

```
// Declare static max value the indicates if safe or busted
var MAX = 21;
var c4 =5;
var c5 =1;
var c6 =4;
var d4 =1;
var d5 =11;
var d6 =1;

var total3 = c4+c5+c6;
var total4 = d4+d5+d6;
// Declares 3 variables to hold results for player, dealer and winner
var player = '';
var dealer = '';
var winner = '';

var printResult = function(player, dealer, winner){
    var game1 = "Player: "+ player +", Dealer: "+ dealer + ", " + winner + " has won.";
    return game1;
}

if (total3 > MAX)
{
    player = 'busted';
}
else
{
    player = 'safe';
}

if (total4 > MAX)
{
    dealer = 'busted';
}
else
{
    dealer = 'safe';
}

if (dealer == 'busted' || (total3 > total4 && player == 'safe'))
{
    winner = 'player';
}
else
{
    winner = 'dealer';
}

printResult(player, dealer, winner);
```

Answer (score 0):

It does exactly what it is supposed to do.
total4(13) is higher than total3 (10).
Also you are putting variables player and dealer to function printResult and you are not using them in scope of a function. Instead you use global variables total3 & total4.

Answer (score -2):

When you get to the second `if` statement you have already changed the variables `total3` and `total4` so what you are comparing is `'busted' > 'safe'`.

Use separate variables for the strings you want to print, do not reuse the existing variables, and use `else if`.

---

Also, check your `printResult` function, it's not using the arguments you pass to it.